# show Listview column wise and and on button click show same listview in rowwise

Tags: c#, listview

I have a task to complete.. i must populate a list view from database and show in column wise and on a button click show it in a row wise... i just completed populating list view from database. now how do i display it it column wise and row wise... please help me...
This is the code i have tried to populate the database...

```
public partial class DtposMDIParentSystem : Form
{
    List<object[]> result = new List<object[]>();

    public DtposMDIParentSystem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //create the database connection
        OleDbConnection aConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\AP_AE\Desktop\DTPOS_APP\DataBase\DtposDatabase.accdb;");

        //create the command object and store the sql query
        OleDbCommand aCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Food", aConnection);

        try
        {
            aConnection.Open();

            //create the datareader object to connect to table
            OleDbDataReader reader = aCommand.ExecuteReader();

            int i = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                result.Add(new Object[reader.FieldCount]);
                reader.GetValues(result[i]);
            }
            reader.Close();
            aConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Masseage = " + ex.Message);
        }

    }

     private void cmdOlives_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (result.Count > 0)
            {
                string temp = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < result[1].Length; i++)
                {
                    temp += result[1][i] + "     ";
                }
                TableOrderListView.Items.Add(temp);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something like that by switching between different view modes:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;

        listView1.Columns[0].Width = listView1.ClientSize.Width - 25;
        listView1.Height = 244;
    }
    else
    {
        listView1.View = View.List;

        listView1.Columns[0].Width = 50;
        listView1.Height = 44;
    }
}
```

You need to add **one** `Column` for `Details` view to work!

Note that you will have to adapt the size of the Listview:

- In `Details` mode it will need to be tall enough to show several items
- In `List` mode it will have to to rather wide but must not be tall enough to show more than one item (plus the scrollbar)!

If instead you mean to switch rows and columns you will have to do that in your datasource!